# Using nav menu to change content container

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers

I have a nav menu and when you click an option I would like it to change my content container to a different content container or make only the appropriate content container to appear. My goal is to consolidate the multiple pages which are the same except for the content container into one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('.option-toggle-selector').on('click', function() {
      $('.my-content-container-selector').replaceWith(otherContainerElement);
 });
```

Where otherCotainerElement could be a jquery element or just a hard coded html string. The key function I think you are asking about here is replaceWith: http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, then you should mark it as the accepted answer. I believe you will be able to now that you have 15 rep. Cheers